# HTTPS on XAMPP server?

Tags: ssl, xampp

i need a way to get a SSL certificate onto my windows XAMPP server (Which people outside of my network should also be able to access).

I have tried using XAMPP's `makecert` method but then chrome gives the error:

> ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: The error clearly says that your host name doesn't match the certificate name. It should be the same as the computer name used to browse it.

Comment: i have set the common name on 127.0.0.1 which is localhost

Comment: That means that for the website to work in the browser you must connect as `https://127.0.0.1`, even using "localhost" will fail. Other computers using the local IP or the server name will also have the very same error. In general, the certificate name must match the address bar in the browser *exactly* to be accepted.

Comment: When i try to connect via https://127.0.0.1 it still gives this error: `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: it also says that `Subject Alternative Names` hasn't been specified. What does that mean?